# How to remove content that is added automatically to body in exchange web service api

Tags: exchangewebservices

firstly I create appointment via exchange web services, then When I look at this appointment body  on microsoft outlook , the body include content as follow. But I don't add  this content as programatically. How to remove this content ?

```
When: Friday, June 09, 2017 10:00 AM-10:30 AM. UTC

*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*
```

Also I set Message body for appintment as follow;

```
MessageBody messageBody = new MessageBody();
messageBody.setBodyType(BodyType.Text);
messageBody.setText("MY TEXT");
appointment.setBody(messageBody);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is by default.

You can do a work-around by saving the invitations to the Drafts folder instead of sending them, then retrieve them and remove the extra text.
Then use UpdateItems to save them to the SentItems folder.

Comment: Interesting,  how can I change default behaviour ?

Comment: ?? I already explained in the answer how to do a work-around. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: When I try to save the invitation to Draft , I get error as following "Cannot create a calendar item in a non-calendar folder." @MadDev